# SANParks conservation fees - per calendar day, or 24-hour period?

Tags: fees-and-charges, south-africa, national-parks

This questions is specifically about Kruger, but I assume it applies to any other parks managed by SANParks. You have to pay a daily fee to enter Kruger (and other parks), [as described here](https://www.sanparks.org/tourism/tariffs/).

My question is whether this fee applies to a 24-hour period, or for each calendar day. For example, if we enter at 3 pm on January 1, and leave before 3 pm on January 2, do we have to pay two days worth of conservation fees, or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in their [conservation fee policy](https://www.sanparks.org/assets/docs/tourism_tariffs/conservation-fee-policy-aug-11.pdf) (PDF file), on the website you linked to.

> Conservation fees were announced as to be payable “daily”. For easier
>   administration however, they will be payable for every night spent in a
>   particular park. In other words, day visitors pay the fee once; guests
>   staying for one night will also pay once, while guests staying two nights will pay twice.